# How to set up Drauger os and Ubuntu dual-boot

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot

I have a desktop with 2 240gb ssd's.  I want to install Ubuntu 21.10 on one, and Drauger OS zombi on the other as a dual-boot.  I have Ubuntu working on one drive, I am using it right now, but now how to set up the drauger so I can dual-boot?  I have not been able to find much on the matter.  I tried using balena etcher to install Drauger on the other internal drive using the drive with ubuntu on it. I do not get the option at boot, to choose which os boots.  It just automatically m boots to ubuntu without letting me choose. How would I set this up right?

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult, the boot loader, GRUB, will identify them both and present you with choices when booting. But isn't Drauger Ubuntu-based? Why would you install them both? I suggest installing Drauger only and if any app is missing add a PPA repo or snap (or even flatpak or appimages) for more apps.

Comment: I want two different linux os's and drauger fits my taste well as it supports many games and wine runs best on it.  I like ubuntu because it is easy to use and reliable. I can't get windows to work, and besides, it is s-l-o-w compared to ubuntu based os's.  What is GRUB?  I don't know what it is; I am a noob at setting up dual-boots.

Comment: I just did some monkeying around trying to set it up. See latest edit.